# Any Performance overhead if the application has more 5000 COM objects?

Tags: performance, visual-c++, com, vb6, activex

We do industrial automation application and we need to use VC++ application. As part of that we need windows controls which shall be developed in Visual Basic 6.0.

When we run the application with tabbed interfaces, we have approximately 5000 COM objects together.

COM object count is expected to grow.

Are are any performance overhead based on usage COM components count within the application?

so far, I don't observe any performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, IE8 does not seem to suffer from having scripts referencing many elements at the same time. I think you need to look elsewhere for performance gain.